# How to get the dispatched route name in Zend framework?

Tags: xml, zend-framework, routes, zend-router

Current state:

- A router is loaded from xml file
- two route name within the router are going to the same controller and action, for example: www-language-employee and www-language-trainer are going to the same controller and action --> EmployeeController & listemployeeAction

Problem:
- Need to know which route name is dispatched/being used from a request.

Example:
1. http://www.mycompany.com/en/trainers/
   Expected return value: www-language-trainer

Answer (score 41):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Zend Framework 1.10.6. Any alternative?

Answer (score 8):

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case :

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName()
```

returns `Employeecontroller/:listemployee`

In `Employeecontroller` :

```
public function listemployeeAction()
{
    $this->getRequest()->getParam('listemployee')
}
```

would return either `employee` or `trainer`