# How to know route from the URL or $request Object?

Tags: zend-framework, request, zend-route

PLOT:

> After implementing ACL on my website, if a user tries to access unauthorised page he will be denied and shown a page to login. After he loggs in, I wanted to redirect the user to the previous page to which he was denied to earlier.

To do this, I store the request parameters using `$request -> getParams()`, onto a session variable, which will be used to generate the url again. **This is where the problem occurs**, to generate the url back, I need the name of the route and that i dont know how to read.

I need to know the route name, so that I will be able to regenerate the url, from the array stored in session, or if there is a better way to solve this, please suggest.

Comment: This has been answered here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373573/how-to-get-the-dispatched-route-name-in-zend-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373573/how-to-get-the-dispatched-route-name-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store `$request->getRequestUri()`? This will give you the URL as it appears in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Dont try to think of complex solutions for simple problem.

You can do this, with just using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, this gives the same result as @Phil's answer (Correct me, If i am missing something). and is more than enough to do what you want.

Comment: Using `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getRequestUri()` handles the differences between various web servers, making the script much more portable.