# Routes and URL Params - ZendFramework

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm having an issue with zendframework routes and params.

I have language selector in my view page:

```
 <div class="language-chooser">
    <?
    $params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
    unset($params['module']);
    unset($params['controller']);
    unset($params['action']);
    ?>
    <a href="<?= $this->url(array_merge($params, array('lang' => 'pt'))); ?>"><img src="<?= $this->baseUrl('/images/flags/br.png'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="<?= $this->url(array_merge($params, array('lang' => 'en'))); ?>"><img src="<?= $this->baseUrl('/images/flags/us.png'); ?>" alt="" /> </a>
</div>
```

It works fine without routes. Accessing localhost/app/contact, I get the link correctly Ex.: localhost/app/contact/index/lang/en

But if I add a route

```
protected function _initRotas() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    '/contact',
                    array(
                        'module' => 'default',
                        'controller' => 'contact',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    )
    );
    $router->addRoute('contact', $route);
}
```

I get the link without the lang param. Ex.: localhost/app/contact/

How could i solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345018/zend-reverse-matching-of-routes-returns-current-url/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is based on the default route, which looks like `:module/:controller/:action/*`
Notice the `*` at the end of the route; it defines that the url can contain additional key/value pairs.

To make your contact route work, you could either use

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/contact/:lang',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'contact',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

this will make the url look like `/contact/pt`. Or you can use:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/contact/*',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'contact',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

Which will result in `/contact/index/lang/pt`

Comment: "Notice the `*` at the end of the route; it defines that the url can contain additional key/value pairs."
=> this is what made me crazy. I needed the star... THX !!!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this code:

```
$Router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$Router->addRoute('move', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/contact/:lang',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'contact',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'lang' => '[a-z]+'
    )
));
```

[Zend_Controller_Front](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.front.html)

[Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)